# Are pods managed by a Deployment restarted when updating a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: updates, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/clusters/upgrade) says that only pods that are managed by a Replication Controller will be restarted after a Kubernetes cluster update on Google Container Engine.

What about the pods that are managed by a Deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the language is too precise. Any pods that are managed by a controller (Replication Controller, Replica Set, Daemon Set, Deployment, etc) will be restarted. The warning is for folks that have created Pods without a corresponding controller. Because nodes are replaced with new nodes (rather than upgraded in place), Pods without a controller ensuring that they remain running will just disappear.

Comment: What do you mean by "is too precise"? Do you have a link other the one I gave above?

Comment: Too precise in the sense that it specifically mentions replication controllers but not any others. If the language said "pods managed by a controller" then it would cover the other controller types. But it was written before the other controller types existed and hasn't been updated to reflect the addition of other controllers.